# To look an EJB , i have to deploy the implementations .jar or interfaces .jar?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi, lookup

I try to look up and EJB under jboss EAP6.
I have 2 mavenized projects :

1. Interfaces where I have justeinterfaces.
2. Implementations where I have only the implementations of interfaces and my tests classes (I use testNG)

My question is: Do I have to deploy on the server the interfaces or the implementations projects?

Comment: Both. How do you expect the EJB Container to inject the implementation of your EJB service if you just deploy an interface?

Comment: i agree with you but how can i do to test some deployed think? and i found that witout deploying that EJB by using JBOSS-EMBEDDED-EJB i can test them wuth TestNG. if you look here you will find what i am asking for :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095490/how-to-look-up-an-ejb-in-a-test-class-but-interfaces-are-in-other-maven-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to deploy the jar of maven project where i have all implementations class